# Coding approach and usage of Dictionary

Tags: c#, dynamic, dictionary, key-value, key-value-coding

I have this set of constants.

```
private const string A1KEY = 'a1';
private const string A1VALUE = 'AONE';
private const string B1KEY = 'b1';
private const string B1VALUE = 'BONE';
private const string C1KEY = 'c1';
private const string C1VALUE = 'CONE';
private const string D1KEY = 'd1';
private const string D1VALUE = 'DONE';
```

And I receive a input of the form.

```
string input = 'a1,b1,d1';
```

So, depending on this input ... my objective is to generate a dynamic script whouch would comprise of the respective values of the keys received in input.

I intend to ,

1) Add the key,value pairs to a Dictionary.
2) Compare the dictionary keys against the input string.
3) Select th respective -values -for keys received.
4) And send that list to a method to generate script.

```
public string GenerateDynamicScript (...)
{
StringBuilder appndScript = new StringBuilder();

appndScript.Append ("alert('the value is <variable>'"); }
```

Is this a right approach? Code samples would be helpful.

What is the efficient method to handle this objective?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Add your values

string keys[] = input.split(',');

return myDict[keys[0]];
```

That's not the whole implementation, but that should get you started.

My C# is a little rusty, may or may not compile.

Comment: It sounds like he needs the dictionary value for each of the keys in the input string, not just the first.

Comment: @Servy Yep, I got that from the question too- I just want to let the asker puzzle it out. They are on track.